# What's the difference between יאכלו נקודים and יתחלקו לעסות (in תרומות פ״ה)?

Tags: rambam, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, bread, teruma, maseches-terumos

A few משניות in chapter 5 of מסכת תרומות discuss טמא wheat kernels that got mixed with טהור ones that never became מוכשרים לקבל טומאה. They say that, to avoid making the טהור ones טמא, we do one of the following with the mixture:

> יאכלו נקודים או קליות או ילושו במי פרות או יתחלקו לעסות כדי שלא יהא במקום אחד כביצה
>
> They shall be eaten as נקודים, or as roasted kernels, or kneaded with fruit juice, or divided into loaves such that there is not an egg's volume in one place.

(Roasted kernels don't get wet, so won't be מוכשרים; fruit juice isn't מכשיר; and less than an egg's volume won't make anything טמא.)

The רמב״ם (on the first משנה, in the יכין ובועז editions) says "נקודים" means

> הוא שיעשנה ככרות קטנות תהיה כל אחת כחצי ביצה וכן אמרו בגמרא ואין הכוונה שילוש אותה כולה ויעשה ממנה ככרות קטנות כחצי ביצה אבל הכוונה שילוש אותה ככר אחר ככר
>
> that he shall make it small loaves, each of which shall be a half egg's size, as they said in the גמרא. And the intent isn't that he will knead it all and make small loaves, a half egg's size: rather, the intent is that he should knead it loaf after loaf.

According to the רמב״ם, what's the difference between the two possibilities "נקודים" and "יתחלקו לעסות כדי שלא יהא במקום אחד כביצה" in the משנה? Meaning both (a) what's the difference in act: aren't they the same case? And then, (b) even if they are different physically, why does the משנה list two such similar cases?

---

(Others explain "נקודים" differently, but my question is according to the רמב״ם's explanation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Mishne Torah Hilchot Terumah chapter 14

יב] סאה תרומה טהורה, שנפלה לפחות ממאה חולין טמאין--יימכר הכול לכוהנים, חוץ מדמי תרומה.  והכוהן אוכל מדומע זה קליות, או ילוש אותו במי פירות שאינן מכשירין--כדי שלא תיטמא התרומה מן החולין הטמאין

|1| או ילוש מדומע זה פחות פחות מכביצה--שאין אוכל טמא מטמא אוכל אחר, עד שיהיה כביצה; 

|2| או יתחלק מדומע זה פחות מכביצה בכל עיסה, כדי שלא תיטמא התרומה שבו.‏

As DoubleAA says following the Yachin, following the Rambam, Nikudim are isolated small quantities of bread dough, but Ythalek leYssot is to partage such little quantities into several big bread doughs.

Your question is very interesting because the Tosfoss Yom Tov asks, following the Rav and Rash, nekudim <=> klayot; you ask, following the Rambam, nekudim <=> Ythalek leYssot

But we can see a "לא זו אף זו" because in the second case (Ythalek leYssot) we introduce intentionally  impure food into a big dough and after that hafrashat hala. It seems perhaps a bit as Bitul Lechatehilla and this is the Hidush.

N.B. There is an astonishment when we see that the Radbaz at this place is not following the Rambam:

ופי' נקודים יבשים כמו יבש היה נקודים (יהושע ט') שלא ילוש אותם כדי שלא יוכשרו לקבל טומאה או ילושו במי פירות דמי פירות אין מכשירין: ‏

It seem's not to correspond with the explanation of Rambam in Mishnayoss and in Mishne Torah.

Comment: Nekudime is litle biscuits, prepared separately
Ythalek leYssot are big loaves of bread. But into each bread, it is important to introduce less than one cabetsa of huline temeine, and it is surely the case if we have less than cabetsa of the melange in each. If it is not clear enough we will try again.